# angular 11 Can't bind to 'allow' since it isn't a known property of 'iframe'

Tags: angular, iframe

I'm trying to embed a youtube video into my website.
This is the code from youtube

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a8xa3dOWJHA" frameborder="0" 
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

And I want to pass the `allow` and `allowfullscreen` like this

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a8xa3dOWJHA" frameborder="0" 
  [allow]="allowList" 
  [allowfullscreen]="doesAllowFullscreen>
</iframe>
```

But I get `Can't bind to 'allow' since it isn't a known property of 'iframe'` from Angular.

I know Angular did develop this [YouTube player component](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/youtube-player) but I find it too complex for what I need.

Does somebody manage to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular's attribute binding syntax (attr prefix) should work:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a8xa3dOWJHA" frameborder="0" 
  [attr.allow]="allowList" 
  [attr.allowfullscreen]="doesAllowFullscreen>
</iframe>
```